# Parameterizing a Tersoff Potential in LAMMPS

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, interatomic-potentials

I am seeking advice regarding a molecular dynamics simulation in LAMMPS of Gallium Phosphide (GaP). I came across a paper by [Powell et al.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.75.115202) which parameterized a tersoff potential for Ga-P interaction, but it did not include the Ga-Ga and P-P interaction parameters. However, the author did find various elastic constants of GaP using that potential. On the other hand, I was able to successfully recreate the tersoff potential for GaN (included in the LAMMPS example directory) from a paper by [Nord et al.](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/15/32/324), which included the Ga-Ga and N-N interaction parameters.

My question is, can I use the parameters from Powell et al. without including the Ga-Ga and P-P interaction parameters, or do I need to use some hybrid potential? I am not sure if this is possible or not. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to proceed with this issue.

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great example of how MD potentials are meant to fit substances *for particular purposes*.

The Tersoff potential is meant to fit the cohesive energy of solid-state structures by modifying the energies *of bonds* in terms of the geometries of *other nearby bonds*. Yes, it's implemented in LAMMPS as a non-bonded potential because that's how LAMMPS represents materials whose bond topologies can change, but you should consider each pair interaction as implicitly a bond.

So why doesn't Powell's paper have Ga-Ga and P-P parameters? Because he studied GaP only in the regime where there was only one type of nearest-neighbour bond, namely the Ga-P bond. And why does Nord's paper have Ga-Ga and N-N parameters? Because *they* were studying Ga and N in high-pressure phases, where all of those bonds *were* relevant.

So the question of whether you need the homoatomic parameters depends on whether *you* expect to see homoatomic bonds at your chosen temperature and density. Note that there is a recent study which used Powell's parameters in LAMMPS (Phys. Rev. B 101 (2020), 024307), so you should try to contact those authors for more information.